# Attaching absolute path to css/js files while building the react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way I could have absolute paths to reach js/css files after I build the react app? I tried the `homepage` thing in package.json which looks like:

```
  {
    "name": "controller",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "homepage": "http://127.0.0.1/controller/",
    "dependencies": {
      "react": "^16.5.2",
      "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
      "react-scripts": "2.0.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not ie <= 11",
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
}
```

But the final output produced has an output which looks like:

```
<script src="/controller/static/js/main.38015169.chunk.js"></script>
```

So the path is from `controller`. The problem occurs when I try to load the react app from a proxy. The scripts start giving 404 error because it searches the scripts on a different domain. How could I make the part as absolute during the react build?

I would want the referencing to look like:

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/controller/static/js/main.38015169.chunk.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try creating `.env` file at the root level. Set `NODE_PATH` to ‘http://127.0.0.1/controller/static/’ or ‘http://127.0.0.1/src/’ I'm not sure. I think that this will work if you are using create-react-app because create-react-app is configured in such a way that its webpack configuration will automatically pick up ‘.env’ files and read the ‘NODE_PATH’ environment variable, which can then be used for absolute imports.

Comment: @evgenifotia What is `NODE_PATH`?

Comment: @evgenifotia Tried having this, but does not work

Comment: Or try doing this instead `<base href="http://127.0.0.1/">` in the head of the index file

Comment: have you tried adding `<base href="http://127.0.0.1/">` to index.html? I think that this one should work because it use HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this by placing a variable called `PUBLIC_URL` in the `.env` file at the root of each react application.

```
PUBLIC_URL=http://127.0.0.1/controller/
```

When the build is made, all javascript/CSS paths start from the value of `PUBLIC_URL`, which is what I had wanted.